# Ricing Xclock Colors

Tags: xorg, desktop, theme, x-resources, color-management

I have edited the `~/.Xresources` file for the forground and backgorund of Xclock:

```
xclock*foreground: #ebdbb2
xclock*background: #282828
```

Only the background shows up. The forground remains the default color.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.